# apache common library for downloading files over http\s protocol

Tags: apache-commons

Given a `link`, say, `Java.sg/downloads`, I need to crawl it for various zip files and download them. Is there an existing `apache commons library` to implement this task?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an Apache library, however I am using [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) for crawling a page and all it's sub-pages with code as follows. Downloading can then be done via URLConnection, see e.g. [this page](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/file-url-download.shtml).

```
    public static void walkAllHtmlPages(final String startURL) throws IOException, SAXException {
    final WebClient webClient = createWebClient();

    try {
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(startURL);
            try {
                Set visitedURLs = new HashSet();

                List links = page.getAnchors();

                // now recursively walk all pages
                recursivelyFollowLinks(webClient, links, visitedURLs);
            } finally {
                if(page != null) {
                    page.cleanUp();
                }
            }
    } finally {
        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }
}

    public static WebClient createWebClient() {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
        webClient.setTimeout(30000);
        webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        webClient.setCssEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAppletEnabled(true);
        webClient.setRedirectEnabled(true); // follow old-school HTTP 302 redirects - standard behaviour

        webClient.setHTMLParserListener(null);
        webClient.setIncorrectnessListener(new IncorrectnessListener() {
            @Override
            public void notify(String message, Object origin) {
                // Swallow for now, but maybe collect it for optional retrieval?
            }
        });
        webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());

        return webClient;
    }

    private static void recursivelyFollowLinks(WebClient webClient, List links, Set visitedURLs) throws SAXException, IOException {
        try {
            for(HtmlAnchor link : links) {
                String url = link.getHrefAttribute();

                if (!visitedURLs.contains(url)) {
                    visitedURLs.add(url);

                    visitSubLink(webClient, visitedURLs, link, url);
                }
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("While retrieving links: " + getLinksAsString(links), e);
        }
    }

    private static void visitSubLink(WebClient webClient,
            Set visitedURLs, HtmlAnchor link, String url) throws IOException, SAXException {
        URL current = link.getPage().getUrl();

        try {
            HtmlPage ret = (HtmlPage)link.click();

            List sublinks = ret.getAnchors();

            recursivelyFollowLinks(webClient, sublinks, visitedURLs);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) { // NOPMD
            throw new RuntimeException("While clicking link: " + link.getId() + " to " + url, e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use wget!

Linux wget examples:
http://linuxreviews.org/quicktips/wget/

Wget for Windows:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: Why the downvote? Wget can be used alone or called from Java, and it includes all the needed functionality in a robust, tested package.